# Скрытие клавиатуры после нажатия кнопки

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

При в вводе какого-то текста в editText виртуальная клавиатура остаётся открыта, как сделать так чтобы она сама скрывалась при нажатии кнопки, какой код должен быть в методе кнопки?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать такой код в котором используется [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html):

```
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

и вот вариант для котлина:

```
this.currentFocus?.let { view ->
    val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

[вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-do-you-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-using-java) можно найти разные варианты реализации решения вашей задачи

Comment: Код для Java почему то не работает, клавиатура всё равно остаётся